# Prove that the $\lim_{x\to a}\sqrt[n]{x}=\sqrt[n]{a}$

Tags: calculus

Can anyone share a way of proving the following limit? I'm looking for an idea that can be used at the Calc I level, using the epsilon delta formal definition.

$$\lim_{x\to a}\sqrt[n]{x}=\sqrt[n]{a}$$

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a search engine, do you mean a hint instead of a link?

Comment: This question is badly stated, but I think it can be salvageable. For instance, there doesn't seem to exist a post concerning the continuity of the $n$-th root in MSE (This one seems close: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268183/prove-that-n-th-root-is-continuous/268187#268187 , but the question on the body of the answer is not exactly the title).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\left|x^{1/n}-a^{1/n}\right|&=\left|\left(x^{1/n}-a^{1/n}\right)\left(\frac{x^{1-1/n}+a^{1/n}x^{1-2/n}+a^{2/n}x^{1-3/n}+\cdots a^{1-1/n}}{x^{1-1/n}+a^{1/n}x^{1-2/n}+a^{2/n}x^{1-3/n}+\cdots a^{1-1/n}}\right)\right|\\\\
&=\frac{|x-a|}{x^{1-1/n}+a^{1/n}x^{1-2/n}+a^{2/n}x^{1-3/n}+\cdots a^{1-1/n}}
\end{align}$$

The case for $a=0$ is straightforward.  For $a>0$, we first take $|x-a|<a/2$.  Then, for $x\in [a/2,3a/2]$, we have

$$x^{1-1/n}+a^{1/n}x^{1-2/n}+a^{2/n}x^{1-3/n}+\cdots a^{1-1/n}\ge n(a/2)^{1-1/n}$$

Therefore, for all $\epsilon>0$,

$$\left|x^{1/n}-a^{1/n}\right|<\epsilon$$

whenever $|x-a|<\delta=\min\left(a/2,n(a/2)^{1-n}\epsilon\right)$

And we are done!

Comment: Very nice answer. This is right at the level I need when Calc I students are seeing this limit for the first time and are still in the second caper. Had to do a little work to verify $\ge n(a/2)^{1-1/n}$. Now, what about if $a<0$? How about a specific example, say $\lim_{x\to-5}\sqrt[3]{x}=\sqrt[3]{-5}$?

Comment: Also, it seems that if $a>0$, then $x^{1-1/n}+a^{1/n}x^{1-2/n}+a^{2/n}x^{1-3/n}+\cdots+a^{1-1/n}$ is simply greater than $(a/2)^{1-1/n}$ if $x>a/2$. So you don't have to deal with the terms after $x^{1-1/n}$, but it was very, very cool the way you dealt with them.

Comment: Thank you.  Much appreciative.  Happy Holidays!  - Mark

Answer (score 3):

Using the binomial theorem, you can show the following extension to the triangle inequality
$$
\left|\sqrt[n]{x_n}-\sqrt[n]{a}\right|\le\sqrt[n]{|x_n-a|}
$$
which allows a simple proof of the limit.

---

*Proof:* Assume first $a≤b$. Then expand $(\sqrt[n]a+\sqrt[n]{b-a})^n$ by the binomial theorem and only keep the two pure powers terms $a+...+(b-a)$ to get the inequality $(…)^n≥b$, or $\sqrt[n]{b-a}\ge \sqrt[n]b-\sqrt[n]a$. Then change the roles of $a$ and $b$ to obtain the other case of the absolute values.

Comment: I'd love to see the detailed steps showing a proof of this inequality.

Comment: @David https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2523550/503397

Answer (score 1):

$f: (0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ given by $f(x)=x^n$ is a continuous injective map in an open interval. Hence, its inverse is continuous (when restricted to the image, of course). Note that a function being continuous does not imply, in general, that its inverse is continuous.

There are many ways to see this, some more elementary than others. One can apply the Invariance of Domain Theorem (of course, this is not what you look for), one can extend the definition of the function by extending both the domain and codomain to the respective two-point compactifications and use the fact that a bijective continuous map on a compact set is continuous (this is more elementary). A direct approach can be seen in [this link](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~js/Math405/405.monotone.pdf). A more elaborate approach on the compactness argument can be seen [here](http://aloiziomacedo.weebly.com/blog/the-extended-real-line-from-a-topological-pov-introduction). The compactness argument also show that $f:[0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous implies the inverse is continuous. (I'm only restricting myself to positve reals due to the fact that $n$ can be even, but the results are obviously the same for the whole real line if $n$ is not even)

---

One can also have the definition that $x^{\alpha}=e^{\alpha \cdot \ln x}$, from which continuity follows trivially.

Answer (score -3):

The function $x \mapsto x^{1/n}$ is continuous everywhere.

Comment: This is a circular hint, since that is exactly the contents of this limit, that the root is continuous in $a$.